# truncated distribution $\mathbb{E}[X^2|1.48<x<1.52]$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

> Exercise $9.12$. * (A Conditioning Problem). Diameters of ball bearings made at
> a factory are normally distributed with mean $1.5$ cm and s.d. $0.02$ cm. Balls whose
> diameter exceeds $1.52$ cm or is less than $1.48$ cm are discarded. The rest are shipped
> for sale. What is the mean and the s.d. of balls that are sent for sale?

SO I am lost.

I think the mean of the ball bearings for sale would not change
but do not know how to calculate  $E\ [X^2|1.48<x<1.52]$
The notes on truncated distributions require knowing $n$ or sigma

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

~Calculus is not my forte.

Comment: In terms of a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) you have told us $\sigma=0.02$

Answer (score 1):

The density of the truncated distribution is the following

$$f_{X|\mu-\sigma<X<\mu+\sigma}(t)=\frac{1}{\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)}f_X(t)$$

now you can calculate your final mean and variance using integrals and tables...

Comment: I honestly do not know how to calculate that ~ I have been working on this for a few hours trying to verify the mean is still 1.5 but have not been able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I honestly do not know how to calculate that ~ I have been working on this for a few hours trying to verify the mean is still 1.5 but have not been able to do that.

the mean is still 1.5 for obvious symmetry properties, but if you want to calculate it analytically, here is the procedure:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|1.48<X<1.52]=\frac{1}{\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)}\int_{1.48}^{1.52}\frac{x}{0.02\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(x-1.5)^2/0.0008}dx=$$

Set $z=\frac{x-1.5}{0.02}$ and get

$$\mathbb{E}[X|1.48<X<1.52]=\frac{1}{\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{(0.02z+1.5)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}dz=$$

$$=\frac{0.02}{\sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)]}\underbrace{\int_{-1}^{1}ze^{-z^2/2}dz}_{=0,\text{ as }f(z)\text{ is odd}}+\frac{1}{\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)}\cdot1.5\cdot[\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)]=1.5$$